# How can I debug dtsx in visual studio 2015?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, ssis

Please tell me, how I can debug `dtsx` in visual studio 2015?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Once you install the SSIS tooling, you just run the package as you normally would any project in visual studio. If you meant something else you need to provide a lot more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many articles talking about this issue you can refer to one of them:

- [Microsoft Docs - Debugging Control Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/troubleshooting/debugging-control-flo)
- [Microsoft Docs - Debug a Script by Setting Breakpoints in a Script Task and Script Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/debug-a-script-by-setting-breakpoints-in-a-script-task-and-script-component)
- [31 Days Of SSIS – Data Flow Breakpoints?! (2/31)](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-using-breakpoints-231/)
- [31 Days Of SSIS – Data Flow Breakpoints?! (3/31)](http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-data-flow-breakpoints-331/)
- [Debugging How-to Topics (Integration Services)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137880(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Steps:

1. Go to the Control Flow and right click on the Data Flow Task (or any task where you want create a breakpoint) and select Edit Breakpoints. Now in the new *Set Breakpoints* window Select *Break when the container receives the OnPostExecute event*. Click OK.
2. Now in the Solution Explorer right click on the package name and click Execute Package. From the menu bar click on the Debug -> Windows -> Watch -> Watch 1. Now at the bottom Watch window will be visible. Under Name type User::VariableName (Whatever variable you are using) and click enter. Under value you can view its value.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16094426)

Comment: @EJoshuaS Updated according to your review.